# How to hide in the dropdown list the required value using ajax and jquery with django

Tags: jquery, django

I have a dropdown list that display the data from the database. I need to make dynamic using jquery and ajax where it will hide some values based on the user input.

**Where the user will have three options to select between and based on his selection the value will show or be hidden in the dropdown list.**

My question is how to hide the required option based on the returning ID.

Until now this what I tried and it did not work as I want.

**views.py**

```
def getSource(request):
    sources = Source.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'create_folder.html', {'sources':sources})
```

**create_folder.html**

```
case"1":
    $('#mouresaleMasdar option[data-id="40"]').hide()
```

and I tried another solution also didn't work.

```
$('#mouresaleMasdar option[value="{{ source.id }}== 40"]').hide()
```

Comment: You need to show enough of your `create_folder.html` the actual html too, not just js. Also check your browser console for any errors.

Answer (score -1):

after a while i found a way to work around this problem where the solution was that i send  dictionary from django views that handle the required value and yo use it in the template.

in views i had to  return the value by filtering based on the ID 
in template i used the django syntax like {{}}  in order to get the dictionary send from django views function.